# javascript single line condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have assignment of values below where value is based on computations for example in the code below.

If the result of

```
(this.dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment / this.metricsData["remainingObligation"])
```

is not a number or infinity then assign the value of this.terminationPaymentPercentageOfTotalObligation to 0

How do we address that in a one line statment in javascript ? Thanks,

[image]

#sample code

```
this.terminationPaymentPercentageOfTotalObligation 
 = ( this.dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment 
     / this.metricsData["remainingObligation"] );

this.terminationPaymentPercentageOfTotalObligation 
  = Math.round(
    this.metricsData["terminationPaymentPercentageOfTotalObligation"]
    * 100);
```

Comment: Are you looking for the ternary conditional operator?  An `if` statement?  It's not really clear what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Don't put a line feed or carriage return after the semicolon. Then it will be all on one line. Seriously, concentrate on making your code functional, maintainable, and understandable, not clever.

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: `if (isNaN(...))`

Comment: @HereticMonkey what do you men by this Don't put a line feed or carriage return after the semicolon. ?

Comment: I mean, don't break the line if you want things to be on one line. Stop worrying about how many lines code takes; in 2021, you should be minifying code, which will take care of getting code into as small a space as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a conditional operator.

```
var x
if(condition) {
  //Do something
  x=1
} 
else {
  //Do something else 
  x=2
}
```

is equivalent to

```
const x = condition ? 1 : 2
```